# La parte superior de mi Reporte Crystal esta tapándose sin razón alguna

Tags: c#, reportviewer, crystal-reports

Buen día, estoy desarrollando una aplicación de facturación con C# Y asp.net, la cual enviara informacion a un RPT formato Crytal y este generara un reporte para imprimir.

Hasta el momento todo funciona normal y estaba funcionando normal, pero de la nada la parte superior del reporte se comenzó a tapar con unos rectángulos como lo muestro a continuación en la imagen, leyendo en foros me indicaron que borrara tanto cache de navegador como temporales, lo hice y se soluciono dejo de taparse el reporte, pero dias despues nuevamente se presento este comportamiento y hasta el momento borrando cache y haciendo lo mismo que se hizo ya no soluciona esto.

[image: REPORTE GENERADO DESDE VISUAL]